# Codeigniter: csrf not working is this case

Tags: codeigniter, csrf

I don't want to change default setting in config file, default it's FALSE. But i want to use CSRF in only contact form (other form don't need):

This is my controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form_helper');
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->config->set_item('csrf_protection', TRUE);
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

End my View:

```
<div id="container">
    <?php echo form_open(NULL); ?>

    </form>
</div>
```

But CSRF not working, it always empty value:

[image]

Comment: Have you set an encryption key in your config file ?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the framework. On a side note CSRF should be enabled on ALL forms anyway.

Comment: i was set encryption key in your config file `$config['encryption_key'] = 'tkppinpin';`

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable CSRF on config.php on each form if enable csrf must use the codeigniter form helper functions.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

**Change**

`$this->load->helper('form_helper');`

**To**

`$this->load->helper('form');`

**application/config/config.php**

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'token';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'cookie_monster';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

**I do not think can use this way.** `$this->config->set_item('csrf_protection', TRUE);`

On each form you must use `<?php echo form_open('yourcontrollerfunction');?>`

If **Null** like on yours returns empty must have controller name you may need to include the index.php if not set htaccess or routes..

`<?php echo form_open('your_controller_name_or_function');?>`

`<?php echo form_close();?>`

**or**

`<?php echo form_open('index.php/your_controller_name_or_function');?>`

`<?php echo form_close();?>`